# How can I make JSON file from a CSV?

Tags: python, json, csv, csvtojson

I have a CSV file with 4 columns(A, B, C, D). Like this:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Example english text | Translated text | Context | Max Length |
| Example english text 2 | Translated text 2 | Context 2 | Max Length 2 |
| Example english text 3 | Translated text 3 | Context 3 | Max Length 3 |

And I need a code, that makes transforms that, to this JSON file:

```
{
  "Context": "Translated text",
  "Context 2": "Translated text 2",
  "Context 3": "Translated text 3"
}
```

I tried this:

```py
import csv
import json


def make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    
    data = {}
    
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)
        
        for rows in csvReader:
            
            key = rows["C"]
            data[key] = rows


    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
        jsonf.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
        

csvFilePath = "main.csv"
jsonFilePath = "test.json"

make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```

But there's an error, and i'm not sure this is the best method.

How can i fix this?

The Error:

```
D:\Python\CSV to JSON>py csvtojson.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\CSV to JSON\csvtojson.py", line 25, in <module>
    make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
  File "D:\Python\CSV to JSON\csvtojson.py", line 14, in make_json
    key = rows["C"]
KeyError: 'C'
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is possible. Please write some code, post the output and any stacktraces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do-

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    csv_data = csv.reader(f)
    json_data = {data[2]: data[1] for data in csv_data}
    
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(json_data, f, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas for it, its will late you do it with very few lines of code.

```py
import pandas as pd
# Read the csv file into Python with help from Pandas
df = pd.read_csv('csv-file.csv')

# Work with your json data in Python
json_data = df.to_json(orient = 'records')

# Save your data into new json file
df.to_json("path\example.json", orient = 'records')
```

Then you load a CSV file into python and convert it to JSON and you are good to go! :)

If you did not have pandas just pip it in

```
pip install pandas
```